# Dynamic basic link in mail markdown with Laravel - not a button

Tags: laravel, markdown, html-email, laravel-5.7

I can generate a basic link like so:

```
This is an [example link](http://example.com/).
```

I can generate a button with a dynamic link like so:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => \URL::to('/subscriptions/'.$recipient->id.'/'.$recipient->email.'?action=subscribe')])
Sign Me Up
@endcomponent
```

But how do I generate a dynamic link, not button?

I tried:

```
[Safe Unsubscribe]( url('/subscriptions/'.$recipient->id.'/'.$recipient->email.'?action=unsubscribe') )
```

and

```
[Safe Unsubscribe]( \URL::to('/subscriptions/'.$recipient->id.'/'.$recipient->email.'?action=unsubscribe') )
```

but these output in a literal way:

```
url('/subscriptions/'.%24recipient-%3Eid.'/'.%24recipient-%3Eemail.'?action=subscribe%27)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are still in a blade template. So if you are not in a blade directive and you want to echo content, you have to use the curly brackets.

```
[Safe Unsubscribe]({{ url('/subscriptions/'.$recipient->id.'/'.$recipient->email.'?action=unsubscribe') }})
```